# How to access set env variable in conanfile.py

Tags: c++, conan

When I use `conan create -e VAR=A . demo/testing` to set a env. variable `VAR=A`,

how can I access the set environment variable inside the `conanfile.py`. The variable `VAR` is not inside `os.environ` dictionary.

I cannot use `export VAR=A`.

```py
import os
import sys
from conans import ConanFile


class BaseLibrary(ConanFile):
  name = "base-library"

  def set_version(self):
    print(os.environ) # does not work... why??
    self.version = "1.0.0"
```

Comment: You have a python script so what is the problem? `os.environ.get('VAR')`?

Comment: The variable is not set in `os.environ`. Especially when I use `os.environ` inside `set_value` function of `class MyProject(ConanFile)`.

Comment: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#method-package-info-env-info

Comment: That does not help, since the self.env_info is not available in `set_version`. Its a bit strange...

Answer (score 2):

The argument `-e` is the environment variable that will be set during the                         package build, which means, passed to the compiler. You can access it, but under the `build(self)` method in your recipe. It's explained on [create](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/creator/create.html) command reference. Thus, you can not access it before building.

As you want to get your environment variable before building, the correct usage is using [tools.get_env](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/tools.html#tools-get-env), but still, you should not use `-e`, it won't work. Instead, you should pass as regular environment variable, before the command:

```
PKG_VERSION=0.1.0 conan create . user/testing
```

```py
from conans import ConanFile, tools

class BaseLibrary(ConanFile):
  name = "base-library"

  def set_version(self):
    self.version = tools.get_env("PKG_VERSION")
```

Still, you can pass the package version by argument, you don't need use env vars (maybe you are using a CI service and don't want to change a config file).

```
conan create . base-library/0.1.0@user/testing
```